# apache pdfBox issue using lineTo and curveTo

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using Apache's PDFBox version 2.0.4 and am having a problem using lineTo and curveTo.  My function takes parameters of radians, starting degrees and ending degrees and then uses lineTo and curveTo to generate a slice of a pie chart.

```
mContents.setNonStrokingColor(color);
mContents.moveTo(0, 0);
List<Float> smallArc = createSmallArc(rad, Math.toRadians(startDeg), Math.toRadians(endDeg));
mContents.lineTo(smallArc.get(0), smallArc.get(1));
mContents.curveTo(smallArc.get(2), smallArc.get(3), smallArc.get(4), smallArc.get(5), smallArc.get(6), smallArc.get(7));
mContents.closePath();
mContents.fill();
```

The pie chart generates and appears to be fine.  My app adds a footer which contains a logo that it reads from a file as follows:

```
try {
    pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(mFullImagePath, mDoc);
}catch(IOException ie){System.out.println("Error opening image file - "+ie.getMessage());}
try {
    mContents.drawImage(pdImage,250,5,pdImage.getWidth()/2,pdImage.getHeight()/2);
}catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error adding image file - "+ e.getMessage());}
```

When the pi chart is included in the pdf generated, the footer and image are not in the pdf.  Stubbing the code to generate the pie chart and the footer shows up with the image included.

Currently have to add the pie chart specifying specific coordinates after the page has been generated otherwise the additional lines below the pie chart do not appear.

Could the curveTo and lineTo generated output be bigger than what is displayed causing these issues?

EDIT - adding the image in the footer before drawing the graph and the image, graph and text all appear.

Appreciate any pointers

Complete code:

```
import com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix;
import org.apache.tomcat.jni.Address;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Calendar; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Locale;

/**  * Created by tim on 7/6/2017.  */
public class ReportDataPDFBox {
    private PDDocument mDoc = null;
    private PDPage mPage = null;
    private PDImageXObject pdImage = null;
    private PDFont mHeaderFont = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

    private final int FONT_SIZE_HDR1 = 16;
    private final int FONT_SIZE_HDR2 = 14;
    private final int FONT_SIZE_REG = 12;
    private final int HDR_INDENT = 30;
    private final int BODY_INDENT_1 = 55;
    private final int BODY_INDENT_2 = 65;
    private final int BODY_INDENT_3 = 75;

    private PDFont mRegFont = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    PDPageContentStream mContents = null;

    private String mReportName = null;
    private String mFullImagePath = null;
    private String mMonth = null;
    private boolean mReportDone = true;
    private int mHorizonVal = 700;
    private int mHorizonGrph = 0;
    private long[] mDayPercent;

    private Calendar mCurrentCalendar = null;
    ProcessFrequencyData pfd = null;
    ProcessWeatherData pwd = null;
    ProcessPerformanceData ppd = null;
    Logger log = null;
    Color[] mColor = {Color.PINK,Color.YELLOW,Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE,Color.RED,Color.GREEN,Color.ORANGE,Color.LIGHT_GRAY};

    public ReportDataPDFBox(Logger logger, ProcessFrequencyData pfd, ProcessWeatherData pwd, ProcessPerformanceData ppd){
        this.log = logger;
        this.pfd = pfd;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.ppd = ppd;
        initializeDoc();
    }

    public void initializeDoc(){
        mDoc = new PDDocument();
        mPage = new PDPage();
        mDoc.addPage(mPage);
        mFullImagePath = "logo.png";
        mCurrentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mMonth = mCurrentCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
        mReportName = mMonth + ".pdf";
        try{
            mContents = new PDPageContentStream(mDoc, mPage);
        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error setting content stream - "+e.getLocalizedMessage());}
    }

    public boolean writeTheReport(){
        addHeader();
        addFooter();

        generateReportContent();

//        addFooter();
        cleanUpALlDone();
        return mReportDone;
    }

    private void addHeader(){
        try {
            mContents.beginText();
            mContents.setFont(mHeaderFont,FONT_SIZE_HDR1);
            mContents.newLineAtOffset(200, 740);
            mContents.showText(mMonth + " - ActoTracker Report - " + mCurrentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            mContents.endText();
        }catch (IOException io){System.out.println("Error with text content screen");}
    }

    private void generateReportContent(){
        addNumberRunInfo();
        addLocationRunInfo();
        addWeekDayInfo();
        addWeekInfo();
        addFrequencyData();
        pukeMeAChart();
           // generateDailyChart();
    }

    private void addNumberRunInfo(){
        int daysActive = Utility.getDaysBetweenDates(Utility.getOldestDate(pfd.getFirstDate(),
    pwd.getFirstDate()), Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        writeLine(mHeaderFont, FONT_SIZE_HDR2,HDR_INDENT, "Frequency Information");
        long percentActiveIdle = (pfd.getTotalDaysRun()*100/daysActive);
        String line = "Number of Runs - " + pfd.getTotalDaysRun() + "    Number of days ActoTracker active - " + daysActive + "   Percent run =
    "+percentActiveIdle;
        writeLine(mRegFont, FONT_SIZE_REG, BODY_INDENT_1, line);
    }

    private void addLocationRunInfo(){
        String line = "Number of locations run = " + pfd.getLocationRun();
        writeLine(mRegFont,FONT_SIZE_REG,BODY_INDENT_1,line);
        for (int i=1; i<=pfd.getLocationRun();i++){
            String[] locationInfo = pfd.getLocationInfo(i);
            long percent = pfd.getRunsByLocation(i)*100/pfd.getTotalDaysRun();
            String line2= new String( locationInfo[0] + " - " + locationInfo[1] +" , "+locationInfo[2]+ "  Number of runs = " +
    pfd.getRunsByLocation(i) + "  Percent of runs = " +percent );
            writeLine(mRegFont, FONT_SIZE_REG,BODY_INDENT_2,line2);
        }
    }

    private void addWeekDayInfo(){
        int totDaysRunning = pfd.getTotalRunDay();
        int leastCnt = 0;
        int mostCnt = 0;
        mHorizonGrph = mHorizonVal - 90;
        mDayPercent = new long[8];
        String mostDay = " most common day";
        String leastDay = " least common day";
        DayFrequencyResults frequency = pfd.getDayDistribution();
        int[] leastDays = frequency.getLessDays();
        int[] mostDays = frequency.getMostDays();
        StringBuilder leastString = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder mostString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i< leastDays.length;i++){
            if (leastDays[i] != 0) {
                leastString.append(Utility.getDayName(leastDays[i])).append(" ");
                leastCnt++;
            }
        }
        for (int j=0; j< mostDays.length;j++){
            if (mostDays[j] != 0) {
                mostString.append(Utility.getDayName(j+1)).append(" ");
                mostCnt++;
            }
        }
        if (leastCnt > 1){leastDay += "s";}
        if (mostCnt > 1) {mostDay +="s";}
        String line = mostString.toString()+mostDay+ " to run"+ "     "+leastString.toString()+leastDay+" to run";
        writeLine(mRegFont,FONT_SIZE_REG,BODY_INDENT_1,line);
        for (int i=1;i<8;i++){
            String day = new String(Utility.getDayName(i)+"  " + pfd.getRweekDayCount(i) + " runs "+" 
    "+pfd.getRweekDayCount(i)*100/totDaysRunning)+ "%";
            writeLine(mRegFont,FONT_SIZE_REG,BODY_INDENT_2,day);
            double x = pfd.getRweekDayCount(i) / (double)pfd.getTotalDaysRun();
            mDayPercent[i] = Math.round(360*x);
        }
        System.out.println("BreakPoint");
    }

    private void addWeekInfo(){
        String line;
        Integer[] largestWeekTotals = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        double largestDistance = 0D;
        double firstHalfDist = 0D;
        double secondHalfDist = 0D;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.##");

        int[] distFreq = pfd.getMonthlySummaryInfo();
        if (distFreq[0] > distFreq[1]){
            line = "Ran more in first half of months run.   "+ distFreq[0] + " times versus "+ distFreq[1]+" times";
        }else{
            line = "Ran more in second half of months run.   " + distFreq[1] + " times versus " + distFreq[0]+" times";
        }
        writeLine(mRegFont,FONT_SIZE_REG, BODY_INDENT_1, line);

        for (int i = 1; i<7;i++){
            if (i<4){
                firstHalfDist += Utility.getMileage(pfd.fa.getWeekDistanceTotal(i),false);
            }else{
                secondHalfDist += Utility.getMileage(pfd.fa.getWeekDistanceTotal(i),false);
            }
        }
        if (firstHalfDist > secondHalfDist){
            line = new String ("Ran further in the first half of the month " + df.format(firstHalfDist) + " miles versus " +
    df.format(secondHalfDist) + " miles");
        }else{
            line = new String ("Ran further in the second half of the month " + df.format(secondHalfDist) + " miles versus " +
    df.format(firstHalfDist)+ " miles");
        }
            writeLine(mRegFont,FONT_SIZE_REG,BODY_INDENT_1, line);
        }

        private void addFrequencyData(){

        int greatestFreq = 0;
        int leastDiff = 0;
        int greatestDiff = 0;
        int leastFreq = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++){
            int cnt = ppd.getRunsByFrequentcy(i);
            if (cnt > greatestFreq){
                greatestFreq = cnt;
                greatestDiff = i;
            }
            else{
                if (cnt > 0 && i>leastDiff){
                    leastDiff = i;
                    leastFreq = cnt;
                }
            }

            log.info("Frequency?? = " + cnt + " index = "+i);
        }
        String line = greatestDiff + " days is the most common frequency between runs "+greatestFreq+" times";
        writeLine(mRegFont,FONT_SIZE_REG,BODY_INDENT_1,line);
        String line2 = leastDiff + " days longest time between runs " + leastFreq + " times";
        writeLine(mRegFont,FONT_SIZE_REG,BODY_INDENT_1,line2);
    }

    private void writeLine(PDFont font, int fontSize, int indent, String text){
        mHorizonVal -= 20;
        try {
            mContents.beginText();
            mContents.setFont(font, fontSize);
            mContents.newLineAtOffset(indent,mHorizonVal);
            mContents.showText(text);
            mContents.endText();
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }

    private void addFooter(){
        log.info("IN addFooter");
        mPage = new PDPage();
        mDoc.addPage(mPage);
        try {
            pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(mFullImagePath, mDoc);
        }catch(IOException ie){System.out.println("Error opening image file - "+ie.getMessage());}
        try {
            mContents.drawImage(pdImage,250,5,pdImage.getWidth()/2,pdImage.getHeight()/2);
        }catch(IOException e){log.error("Error adding image file - "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());}
    }

    private void cleanUpALlDone(){
        try {
            mContents.close();
            mDoc.save(mReportName);
            mDoc.close();
        }catch (IOException ie){System.out.println("Error closing PDF document - " + ie.getMessage());}
    }

    private void generateDailyChart(){
        int totalVal = 0;
        try {
            mContents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(375, 525));
        }catch(IOException e){}

        for (int i=1; i< 8;i++){
            totalVal += mDayPercent[i];
            writeTheChart(mDayPercent[i-1], totalVal,mColor[i]);
            log.info("Color selected = " +mColor[i] +"Index = "+i);
        }
    }

    private void writeTheChart(long beg, long end, Color color){
        try {
            log.info("Color received = " + color);
            drawSlice(color, 60,beg, end);
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }

    private void pukeMeAChart(){
        try {
            mContents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(375,525));
            drawSlice(Color.YELLOW, 60, 0, 69);
            mContents.fill();
            drawSlice(Color.BLUE, 60, 69, 117);
            drawSlice(Color.RED, 60, 117, 181);
            mContents.fill();
            drawSlice(Color.WHITE, 60, 181, 208);
            mContents.fill();
            drawSlice(Color.GREEN, 60, 208, 272);
            mContents.fill();
            drawSlice(Color.YELLOW, 60, 272, 336);
            drawSlice(Color.BLUE, 60, 336, 360);
            mContents.fill();
        } catch(IOException e ){}
    }

    private void drawSlice(Color color, float rad, float startDeg, float endDeg) throws IOException
    {
        mContents.setNonStrokingColor(color);
        mContents.moveTo(0, 0);
        List<Float> smallArc = createSmallArc(rad, Math.toRadians(startDeg), Math.toRadians(endDeg));
        mContents.lineTo(smallArc.get(0), smallArc.get(1));
        mContents.curveTo(smallArc.get(2), smallArc.get(3), smallArc.get(4), smallArc.get(5), smallArc.get(6), smallArc.get(7));
        mContents.closePath();
        mContents.fill();
    }

    private List<Float> createSmallArc(double r, double a1, double a2)
    {
        // Compute all four points for an arc that subtends the same total angle
        // but is centered on the X-axis
        double a = (a2 - a1) / 2;
        double x4 = r * Math.cos(a);
        double y4 = r * Math.sin(a);
        double x1 = x4;
        double y1 = -y4;
        double q1 = x1*x1 + y1*y1;

        double q2 = q1 + x1*x4 + y1*y4;
        double k2 = 4/3d * (Math.sqrt(2 * q1 * q2) - q2) / (x1 * y4 - y1 * x4);
        double x2 = x1 - k2 * y1;
        double y2 = y1 + k2 * x1;
        double x3 = x2;
        double y3 = -y2;

        // Find the arc points' actual locations by computing x1,y1 and x4,y4
        // and rotating the control points by a + a1

        double ar = a + a1;
        double cos_ar = Math.cos(ar);
        double sin_ar = Math.sin(ar);

        List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
        list.add((float) (r * Math.cos(a1)));
        list.add((float) (r * Math.sin(a1)));
        list.add((float) (x2 * cos_ar - y2 * sin_ar));
        list.add((float) (x2 * sin_ar + y2 * cos_ar));
        list.add((float) (x3 * cos_ar - y3 * sin_ar));
        list.add((float) (x3 * sin_ar + y3 * cos_ar));
        list.add((float) (r * Math.cos(a2)));
        list.add((float) (r * Math.sin(a2)));
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it doesn't apply. Could you please upload a good and a bad result file to a sharehoster? Also add more code so that one can see where the content stream(s) is/are created and where closed.

Comment: I upgraded  PDFbox to 2.0.7 with the same result.  Calling code to add a footer image after drawing the pie chart results in no image appearing for the footer.

Comment: Formatting is a bit messy... but what I can see is `mContents.transform()`. Be aware that this transformation stays, unless you use `saveGraphicsState()` before transforming and `restoreGraphicsState()` after you've done your things. If you don't do that, your "250,5" will be relative to previous transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to your assumption, you are **not** *having a problem using lineTo and curveTo*, i.e. your method `drawSlice`. You are having problems in the code *using that method*, i.e. here:

```
private void pukeMeAChart(){
    try {
        mContents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(375,525));
        drawSlice(Color.YELLOW, 60, 0, 69);
        mContents.fill();
        drawSlice(Color.BLUE, 60, 69, 117);
        drawSlice(Color.RED, 60, 117, 181);
        mContents.fill();
        drawSlice(Color.WHITE, 60, 181, 208);
        mContents.fill();
        drawSlice(Color.GREEN, 60, 208, 272);
        mContents.fill();
        drawSlice(Color.YELLOW, 60, 272, 336);
        drawSlice(Color.BLUE, 60, 336, 360);
        mContents.fill();
    } catch(IOException e ){}
}
```

This method starts by translating the coordinate system

```
mContents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(375,525));
```

and does not undo that translation when it is finished. Thus, *the footer and image **are** in the pdf*, merely not where you would expect them but instead translated, probably outside the crop box.

To undo the translation (and other changes, too, like the fill color), simply store the graphics state at the start of `pukeMeAChart` and restore it at the end of it.

Furthermore, `drawSlice` *fills* the slice itself, so there is no path to fill in `pukeMeAChart` anymore. Thus, the `fill` calls there are invalid.

All changes applied:

```
private void pukeMeAChart(){
    try {
        mContents.saveGraphicsState();
        mContents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(375,525));
        drawSlice(Color.YELLOW, 60, 0, 69);
        drawSlice(Color.BLUE, 60, 69, 117);
        drawSlice(Color.RED, 60, 117, 181);
        drawSlice(Color.WHITE, 60, 181, 208);
        drawSlice(Color.GREEN, 60, 208, 272);
        drawSlice(Color.YELLOW, 60, 272, 336);
        drawSlice(Color.BLUE, 60, 336, 360);
        mContents.restoreGraphicsState();
    } catch(IOException e ){}
}
```

---

`generateDailyChart()`, another method (indirectly) using the `drawSlice` method, also has the graphics state issue and has to be fixed similarly:

```
private void generateDailyChart(){
    mContents.saveGraphicsState();
    int totalVal = 0;
    try {
        mContents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(375, 525));
    }catch(IOException e){}

    for (int i=1; i< 8;i++){
        totalVal += mDayPercent[i];
        writeTheChart(mDayPercent[i-1], totalVal,mColor[i]);
        log.info("Color selected = " +mColor[i] +"Index = "+i);
    }
    mContents.restoreGraphicsState();
}
```

As it currently is commented out and, therefore, not used, this problem does not show yet, though.

Comment: save and restore of the graphics state resolved the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: The superfluous `fill` instructions also result in invalid page content, a `fill` only is allowed after a path definition. PDF viewers probably do not complain, though, they tend to be pretty lax.